# Angular velocity, angular acceleration and it's observer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, angular-velocity

[image: problem]

[image: solution]

I was solving the problem above and realized that I was wrong somewhere.

I did two approaches but one didn't work well.

**1.** let one end which is at hold be the point we calculate torque.

Then, $\frac{1}{2}lmg=\frac{1}{3}ml^2\alpha$ (here $\alpha$ denotes $\frac{d\omega}{dt}$), $\alpha=\frac{3g}{2l}$.

Using the relationship between angular acceleration and angular velocity, one could calculate that $a_{end}=l\alpha=\frac{3}{2}g$. This corresponds with intuition since rotation radius of the free end seen at the other end is $l$.

Also,$mg-R=ma_{CM}$  and $a_{CM}=\frac{l}{2}\alpha$ leads to $R=\frac{1}{4}mg$. Here, claculating $a_{CM}$ also seems not strange.

**2.** This is second approach which is shown in the solution above and which makes me struggle.

let CM be the point which we calculate torque about.

$mg-R=ma_{CM}$  also holds here and by torque equation, $\frac{l}{2}R=\frac{1}{12}ml^2\alpha$

Using these two, $\alpha=\frac{6R}{ml}$

Next step is where I'm stuck. The solution says $a_{CM}=\frac{l}{2}\alpha$ as highlighted above, but I don't understand. Why do we have $\frac{l}{2}$ factor?

If $\alpha$ depends on observer, we calculated $\alpha$ putting CM in origin. Then how can I calculate the origin's linear acceleration?

If $\alpha$ does not depend on observer, why on earth $\frac{l}{2}$ is used?

Thanks in advance for reading my poor english and answering my question.

Comment: About the pivot considering the motion of the centre of mass and differentiating with respect to time, $s = \frac l2 \theta \Rightarrow v = \frac l2 \omega \Rightarrow a = \frac l2 \alpha$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha$ is not observer dependent. Now as far as l/2 is considered , it is used because the motion is such that the person which is holding the rod acts as a stationary centre for the motion of the body which is at a distance of $l/2$ from the centre.